# run two tasks in parallel, android

Tags: android

I want to make an android application. my application will find your current location using openstreetmap and then it will find your current weather using openWeatherAPI.
finding location and then finding weather is pretty slow operations. Is there a way to make them run in parallel in background?

Comment: How would you find the weather without first knowing the device location? How will you know what geographic area to find the weather for?

Comment: @Peter I just ask if I could find location then weather in the background??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AsyncTask is what you are looking for.  I have included the link to the developer site.

You will have to subclass AsyncTask to use it and override the doInBackground, onProgressUpdate, and onPostExecute Methods.  You will put the code to get the weather in the doInBackground method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html